# getting syntax error while executing yo command, here i have attached the output

Tags: syntax, token, yo

[click here to see yo command output highlighted and the error,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcBKr.png)

i tried to install yo using command
npm install -g yo

Please help to come out of this issue
node version is: v8.17.0
npm version is: 6.13.4
git version 2.33.0
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350